# How to convert JSON object as a value in a column in SPARK AZURE-DATABRICKS using SCALA as per requirement

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

Guys Can someone help me in resolving the below problem:

I have a spark dataframe in which one of the column's values is coming in JSON format. Please find the below screen shot for your reference:
[image: Column - ratings]

My requirement is as follows:

1. I have to select the "average_rating" attribute which is not null out of all the 3 objects in a single row. If there is none I take null. I have to add this value to the column "Average_Rating". I have to select the "STATUS" from the object where "average_rating" is not null and add the value to a column "average_rating_status".
2. I have to select the "number_of_recent_voters" attribute which is not null out of all the 3 objects in a single row. If there is none I take null. I have to add this value to the column "number_of_recent_voters". I have to select the "STATUS" from the object where "number_of_recent_voters" is not null and add the value to a column "number_of_recent_voters_status".
3. I have to select the "number_of_voters" attribute which is not null out of all the 3 objects in a single row. If there is none I take null. I have to add this value to the column "number_of_voters". I have to select the "STATUS" from the object where "number_of_voters" is not null and add the value to a column "number_of_voters_status".

I have to write the code in scala in my Azure data bricks notebook. Can anyone please help with the code.

Thank you

Edit:

```py
+------------+----------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------+
| compliance | average_rating | number_of_recent_voters | number_of_voters | average_rating_status | number_of_recent_voters_status | number_of_voters_status |
+------------+----------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------+
| true       | 4.7            | 254                     | 254              | PASS                  | PASS                           | PASS                    |
+------------+----------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Output should come like above.

Comment: can you please add input json and expected output ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have the above dataframe having columns "compliance" and "ratings". After transformation, the dataframe should have the columns: "compliance", "average_rating", "number_of_recent_voters", "number_of_voters", "average_rating_status", "number_of_recent_voters_status", "number_of_voters_status"

Comment: please add some sample json messages for us to write code, it is difficult to create json from above message.

Comment: ```scala
val data = List(
  (true, """[{"average_rating":4.7,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":254,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":254,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"}]""")
)

val df = data.toDF("compliance","rating")
display(df)
```

Is the above good enough?

Comment: SO is not a place to ask people to code for you. Show us what you tried and what is blocking you or you don't know how to do.

Comment: No Sir, I am a beginner in this I am unable to find how to approach this

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: version:-- 10.4

Comment: hey there is no spark version 10.4 :D .. max spark version is 3.4

Comment: I mean version 3.2.1, scala 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```scala
val data = List(
  (true, """[{"average_rating":4.7,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":254,"status":"FAIL"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":254,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"}]"""),
  (true, """[{"average_rating":2.7,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":123,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":324,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"}]""")
).toDF("compliance", "rating")
data.show(false)



import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_json, row_number}
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("rating")
val data1 = data.withColumn("row_number", row_number.over(windowSpec))
val data2 = data1.selectExpr("compliance", "row_number", """inline_outer(from_json(rating, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<average_rating DOUBLE, number_of_recent_voters DOUBLE, number_of_voters DOUBLE, status STRING>>'))""")
data2.show()


val data3 = data2.groupBy("row_number").max("average_rating","number_of_recent_voters","number_of_voters").withColumnRenamed("max(average_rating)","average_rating").withColumnRenamed("max(number_of_recent_voters)","number_of_recent_voters").withColumnRenamed("max(number_of_voters)","number_of_voters")
data3.show(false)

val data4 = data3.join(data2, Seq("row_number", "average_rating"), "inner").select(data3.col("*"), data2.col("status")).withColumnRenamed("status","average_rating_status")
display(data4)

val data5 = data4.join(data2, Seq("row_number","number_of_recent_voters"),"inner").select(data4.col("*"),data2.col("status")).withColumnRenamed("status","number_of_recent_voters_status")
display(data5)

val data6 = data5.join(data2, Seq("row_number","number_of_voters"),"inner").select(data5.col("*"),data2.col("status")).withColumnRenamed("status","number_of_voters_status")
display(data6)
```

This code adds a  `row_number`  column to the dataframe using the  `row_number`  function and the window specification defined on `rating` field.  It uses the  `from_json`  function to parse the  `rating`  column as an array of structs, and then uses the  `inline_outer`  function to explode the array into separate rows.  It groups the resulting dataframe by the  `row_number`  column and calculates the maximum value of the  `average_rating`,  `number_of_recent_voters`, and  `number_of_voters`  columns for each group.  It then joins the resulting dataframe with the original dataframe on the  `row_number`  and  `average_rating`  columns, and selects the  `status`  column from the original dataframe. It renames the  `status`  column to  `average_rating_status`.
Similarly, it is done for the  `number_of_recent_voters`  and  `number_of_voters`  columns, and renames the  `status`  columns to  `number_of_recent_voters_status`  and  `number_of_voters_status`, respectively.

The resulting `dataframe` `data6` has the required results.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. Just one thing here, instead of String the ratings column has array object so the from_json command is not working. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Could you share the input dataframe

Comment: @Ashwin I removed the from_json part and continued with inline outer as the object was already in JSON and it worked. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fron_json` with schema & below is sample solution.

```
scala> val data = List(   (true, """[{"average_rating":4.7,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":254,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":254,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"}]""") ).toDF("compliance","rating")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [compliance: boolean, rating: string]

scala> data.show(false)
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|compliance|rating                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|true      |[{"average_rating":4.7,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":null,"number_of_voters":254,"status":"PASS"},{"average_rating":null,"number_of_recent_voters":254,"number_of_voters":null,"status":"PASS"}]|
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> data.printSchema
root
 |-- compliance: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- rating: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> val finalDF = data.selectExpr("compliance", """inline_outer(from_json(rating, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<average_rating DOUBLE, number_of_recent_voters DOUBLE, number_of_voters DOUBLE, status STRING>>'))""")
finalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [compliance: boolean, average_rating: double ... 3 more fields]
```

```
scala> finalDF.printSchema
root
 |-- compliance: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- average_rating: double (nullable = true)
 |-- number_of_recent_voters: double (nullable = true)
 |-- number_of_voters: double (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> finalDF.show(false)
+----------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------+------+
|compliance|average_rating|number_of_recent_voters|number_of_voters|status|
+----------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------+------+
|true      |4.7           |null                   |null            |PASS  |
|true      |null          |null                   |254.0           |PASS  |
|true      |null          |254.0                  |null            |PASS  |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------+------+
```

Comment: Status should be there for all the 3 fields. As for the object average_rating there should be a column average_rating_status and similarly for each of the other 3 fields there should be corresponding status columns

Comment: In your sample data those fields are not available.. please check once.

Comment: It is needed to be manually created as mentioned in the above problem statement

Comment: Can it be done?